# Need to write a search box for joomla that opens a new link

Tags: php, jquery, html, joomla, textbox

Ok I know this is vague and I'm not an expert but I am wiling to write this by myself that's why I need to ask. I have tried googling but this thing is a little bit specific so I haven't found much info.

I need to know where to start first.

What I need:

To implement a text box (search box) in a joomla site in which user enters a "name".
After that the script checks for the list of names and its according IDs and sends the user to a desired link with the ID number of that "name"

Example:

I want to search for a name "Justin" and I type it in the box.
After I click search I get sent to www.names.com/id/3274 (id of the name)

Where do I start?
Can I write this in JQuery? I know html/css/jquery.
Can it be implemented in joomla?
Do I have to write it in PHP?

Just tell me where to start and I would be really grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you will need to access your database to find the id matching the name, you will need something else than javascript. Your "search box" will actually be a text input inside a form which points to a php script. You will need to sanitize the user input (to avoid injections), then do a database query with this input, and if the query result is fine, redirect to the page with the id.

Comment: There's no way around having to write server side PHP to process and route the request.  You have any experience writing extensions in Joomla?

Comment: And you might want to consider using AJAX to connect your Javascript function to your PHP file... you can use jQuery to create the AJAX request, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your ids and names, so you need to create a component to create/edit/delete these values in back-end, so I'm afraid you also need to use PHP.

You can find more info about building Joomla component at [http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development)